# How to add special character in LaTeX?

Tags: latex, special-characters, symbols, tex

In my current work I need to use arrow symbols, representing injection, surjection and bijection. First two can be given by commands `\rightarrowtail` and `\twoheadrightarrow`, but the bijection arrow - [Unicode 2916 character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2916/index.htm) - is not present in the [list of LaTeX arrow characters](http://www.combinatorics.net/weblib/A.7/a7.html). How can I add the mentioned symbol in my text ? Maybe some additional packages should be used ?

I'm new to LaTeX, so any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at [“How to look up a math symbol?”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol) on http://tex.stackexchange.com for ideas how you can easily find a particular LaTeX symbol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can emulate it like this :

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

$\rightarrowtail\!\!\!\!\!\rightarrow $

\end{document}
```

I would also advise looking at the [Comprehensive LaTeX symbol List](http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/CTAN/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) in general.

Answer (score 3):

Using the great [Detexify2 - LaTeX symbol classifier](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) tool I found `\twoheadrightarrow` and `\rightarrowtail` which both combined build the wanted arrow. You can use TeX macro `\kern` to adjust the kerning between the symbols. However, I found that it doesn't produce the correct alignment in all size (e.g. `\tiny` uses different versions of the symbols), so be careful. The combination should be placed inside `\mathrel{..}` to get the correct surrounding spacing to the symbols before and after.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand*{\twoheadrightarrowtail}{\mathrel{\rightarrowtail\kern-1.9ex\twoheadrightarrow}}
% Alternative which doesn't look as good using the normal size, but might work better with smaller sizes too:
%\newcommand*{\twoheadrightarrowtail}{\mathrel{\rlap{$\rightarrowtail$}\twoheadrightarrow}}

\begin{document}

$ A \twoheadrightarrowtail B $

\end{document}
```

[image]